# CoreMotion Attitude Reference Frame

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

What is the difference between  **startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame** CMAttitudeReferenceFrame

1. XArbitraryZVertical
2. XArbitraryCorrectedZVertical
3. XMagneticNorthZVertical
4. XTrueNorthZVertical

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical).`XMagneticNorthZVertical` and `XTrueNorthZVertical` need compass calibration.

Answer (score 0):

*As per Apple help documentation*, CMAttitudeReferenceFrame indicates the reference frame from which all CMAttitude samples are referenced.

Definitions of each reference frame is as follows:

1. **CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical** describes a reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points in an arbitrary direction in the horizontal plane.
2. **CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryCorrectedZVertical** describes the same reference frame as CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical with the following exception: when available and calibrated, the magnetometer will be used to correct for accumulated yaw errors. The downside of using this over CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical is increased CPU usage.
3. **CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical** describes a reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points toward magnetic north. Note that using this reference frame may require device movement to  calibrate the magnetometer.
4. **CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical** describes a reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points toward true north. Note that using this reference frame may require device movement to  calibrate the magnetometer.